# Text Logo as an SVG for vector

Tags: vector, web, svg

I have a text logo using Proxima Nova and I'd like to make it vector.

How do I convert Proxima Nova text to SVG to include as an image on a website?

I have no idea on including SVGs but what I've done so far has given me no luck at all.

Comment: Never have seen, pdf used embedded on site as it is done for images.

Answer (score 1):

Use an application that generates SVGs like Inkscape.